# Appended lines to SVG not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jvectormap

I'm making use of JVectormap, on which i've placed dots. Between these dots I draw lines using:

```
var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
newLine.setAttribute('id','line2'); 
newLine.setAttribute('stroke','white'); 
newLine.setAttribute('stroke-width','1'); 
newLine.setAttribute('stroke-linecap','round'); 
newLine.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray','2, 5'); 
newLine.setAttribute('x1', 0);
newLine.setAttribute('y1', 0);
newLine.setAttribute('x2', 100);
newLine.setAttribute('y2', 200);
$("#map").append(newLine);
```

This results in new dashed lines being added in the correct places, yay!
But the trouble starts when I resize my window, the lines stay fixed to their initial placement. Is there a way/trick to make my lines scale with the map?

**EDIT:**

I've created A fiddle with my current scenario (though the fiddle works perfectly, my map does not):

https://jsfiddle.net/2k6p8yj4/

Because I make use of JVectormap, I have to run my custom map/EPS file through the JVectormap converter. This converter removes the viewBox attribute from my SVG, therefore I've added a new viewBox through JavaScript (see the fiddle) as the comments below implied is necessary.

My map scaling down correctly, but my lines are 'fixed' to the place where they're initially drawn.

**EDIT:**

Here is my running version:

http://sensplugins.jouwtestwebsite.nl/sens-svg-map/

Comment: `coord is not defined` can't test your code.

Comment: Added x and y point coordinates

Comment: If you want SVG to be responsive the outer `<svg>` element normally needs to have a viewBox attribute. Does yours?

Comment: It originally does, but for it to work with JVectormap you have to convert is using their svg converter, which removes the viewBox attribute.

Comment: DOM inspector says your viewBox is viewBox="0 0 function (d,e)..." which is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, my bad fixed it so it displays my bug.